# How do I add error handlers to AngularJS $resource service calls?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service in my app, which works

```
myServices.factory('Auth', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return {
      Login: $resource(serviceURL + 'portal/admins/login', {}, { go: { method:'POST', isArray: false }}),
      Logout: $resource(serviceURL + 'portal/admins/logout', {}, { go: { method:'POST', isArray: false }})
    };
  }
]);
```

How do I add an error handler?

I have tried this as per Explosion Pills suggestions, but it doesn't work :(

```
Auth.Get.go({...}, function(response){
    // Success everyhting is good
}).$promise.error(function(error) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

This is the error that I get:

Error: 'undefined' is not a function (near '...}).$promise.error(function(data) {...')

Thanks Explosion Pills...just needed to add a bit more to the promise code

```
Auth.Login.go().$promise.then(function(data) {
               //Success
             }, function(error) {
               //Error
             });
```

Comment: `myServices.Login.go().$promise.error`

Comment: Can you show me how I would implement this based on my code? I've tried a tonne of different things and isn't working :s

Comment: I don't understand ... the code I have is everything.  You just need to pass a callback function to the `error` method to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) says:

> The Resource instances and collection have these additional properties:
>
> $promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
>
> [...]
>
> On failure, the promise is resolved with the http response object, without the resource property.

Comment: Can you show me how I would implement this based on my code? I've tried a tonne of different things and isn't working :s